# RxJS Debounced method fired multiple times

Tags: typescript, rxjs, debouncing

I tried to create a method that waits for the user to stop writing to send only one API request afterwards.

I dont know why but MyCode() is executed multiple times.

[image]

My code:

```
async functionASDF(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   let source = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
   source.pipe(debounceTime(250)).subscribe(c =>{
      MyCode();
   });
}
```

Comment: How often do you execute `functionASDF`? Also on keyup? You do not need the async keyword here.

Comment: Every time i press a key

Comment: You should only execute it once. Does your code behave in the following way (If you have a delay of more than 250ms): First keypress "1 asdf", second keypress "2 additional asdf", third keypress "3 additional asdf" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it in the following way: Just remove the function, or if you are in a class, execute this inside the constructor. (But make sure that you unsubscribe if the stream is not needed anymore. Otherwise you create a memory leak.)

```js
let source = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
source.pipe(debounceTime(250)).subscribe(c =>{
  MyCode();
});
```

If you only need a keyup from a specific Dom element, e.g. an input, you can replace `document` by that element.